# makeEWSRequestAsync() fails with error 401 in Outlook clients intermittently

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

We have an outlook add-in that uses EWS-APIs (makeEWSRequestAsync()). For most users, our add-in works correctly in OWA, MAC and Windows clients.

Unfortunately however, we have some users who are experiencing intermittent HTTP-401 errors when using our add-in on Windows Outlook. However when users close-then-restart Outlook, and try our add-in again, it starts working. These users are using an Exchange-on-Premise backend.

We checked the network packets and found that in cases where the add-in fails, we see the HTTP-error 401 and a missing call for GetClientAccessToken(). [I have uploaded a screenshot of the network packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq5NR.jpg).

After closing-then-restarting outlook, and re-running our add-in, the add-in now successfully runs and a call to GetClientAccessToken() is observed in the network packets. [A screenshot of this successful execution was uploaded too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdviX.jpg).

What could possibly cause such a behavior on Windows Outlook clients? Why does it work after an Outlook-reset and starts getting http-401 errors after some time?

Conversely, as a workaround, I am thinking of making a [getCallbackTokenAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-getcallbacktokenasync-member(2)) before the makeEWSRequestAsync() call to forcibly execute authentication. I haven't tried it yet though.

I have filed a ticket on Microsoft's github as well. Though I think MS' github is not the right venue for such questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Various exchange services can be tested with online test-connectivity tool from Microsoft. So, you may test the EWS connectivity as follows and see it works. If not, adjust the code or server settings.

1. Open https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com.
2. Select Office 365 or Exchange Server as per your setup.
3. Select `Service Account Access` and perform `Test`.

> Conversely, as a workaround, I am thinking of making a getCallbackTokenAsync() before the makeEWSRequestAsync() call to forcibly execute authentication. I haven't tried it yet though.

You are on the right avenue. The token may expire, so the best way to try retrieving the token anew (in case of exceptions).

Comment: Hello @Eugene. Thank you for taking time to read and give your insights. I will try the getCallBackTokenAsync() as advised. As for token expiration, I understand your point. But in theory, if we close the addin and re-invoke makeEWSRequestAsync(), a new token will be provided right? Or Does this API cache old tokens? In the problematic environments, makeEWSRequestAsync() gets the 401 error repeatedly after closing and opening the addin. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you see any connectivity problems with Exchange when using tools mentioned in the problematic environment?

Comment: Hello Eugene, I am currently asking the affected user (different domain) to test their setup. I will update this comment with the data once I have the results. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the late response Eugene. So I was able to get some network capture packets from the end user with this issue. It turns out, it is indeed token-expiration. Since we are using the makeEWSRequestAsync() call to both authorize and send the SOAP requests, how can I force it to request a new token? Thanks.

Comment: OfficeJS doesn't provide anything specific for refreshing the token. Did you try to use `Office.context.auth` or `OfficeRuntime.auth` namespaces for calling the `getAccessToken` method? Do you get the same results or the token is refreshed after?